# How to traverse Table data in Java and pass that to servlet for using in JSP

Tags: java

I am a PHP programmer and got to know that for me Object oriented-ness, Strict type, and missing powerful array from PHP can be a big problem in Java. 
I tried to get code related to above question but no one works.

My questions:

How to traverse table in various way?
Is there any good tutorial for me related to collection that can be helpful for PHP programmer. I learned Oracle tutorial but that has not solved my problem. That may require lots of attention! I need practical way to learn.
Is there any good method to know how object are structured inside? In PHP I can use print_r, var_dump and can see what is inside.

Here is more explanation asked by a commenter:

```
 try {  
   ArrayList Rows = new ArrayList();  

   while (resultSet.next()){  
   ArrayList row = new ArrayList();  
   for (int i = 1; i <= 7 ; i++){  
           row.add(resultSet.getString(i));  
   }  

   Rows.add(row);  
}
```

Here, do I have a leisure to add complete rows at a time and use that in ArrayList? I do not want to use getString()/getInteger() etc on each column. Or in Java, I need to get every column data one by one.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow.com! Your question is too vague to answer meaningfully. Please post the code you already have, and tell us what exactly does not work. Then we can probably help :-).

Comment: I have messed up the code in trying. I can give code tomorrow. between can you give answers for subquestions (Q# 2 and 3). Those are equally important, so that I can teach myself.

Comment: Use a debugger to see what is inside objects. Also, I want to add that capital variable names (like "Rows") are discouraged, and you should refer to types by the interface instead of the class (`List rows = new ArrayList()`, `List row = new ArrayList()` and stuff like `Map theMap = new HashMap()` instead of `HashMap theMap = new HashMap()`).

Comment: The best practice is to create your entity, then in Data Access Layer (DAL) populate its fields from the database and then use it in your JSP page. While it can seen as "over-engineering", it fact you probably will soon discover that it's much better than how you did this in PHP.

Comment: I will check in netbeans about getting the object's structure. Please continue adding more solutions and comments.

Answer (score 1):

The standard Java release has no way to conveniently dump a collection.  I would be surprised, however, if you couldn't find a non-standard class that does this.

That being said, if you run your code in an IDE and use the debugger you can get what you want pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

In the past i use this library : [jbeandumer](http://code.google.com/p/jbeandumer/downloads/list) it worked for me.
Here is an [introduction](http://code.google.com/p/jbeandumer/).

Comment: It could be interesting to use that. It looks that it can be helpful. Very slowly I am going into Java from PHP.